# Why are menu, vote and 'add comment' clicks ignored on Stack Exchange sites on my mobile device?

Tags: bug, status-completed, mobile-web

About a week ago, the mobile version of Stack Overflow was working as expected on my Windows Phone. Since then, the menu button at the top right of the screen, the voting buttons and the 'add comments' links have stopped responding - clicking them has no effect. In a comment to this question there is a report of similar behaviour on an iPhone.

Deleting my browsing history did not make any difference.

I first noticed this on my Windows Phone 7, but I have since been able to reproduce similar behaviour in Internet Explorer 9 on a PC. This can be accessed via the 'mobile' link at the bottom of the page.

The experience that I have on the PC (with the mobile site) is described below. I understand from the comments that the mobile version is not supported on the desktop, but I have included it because I feel that the problems may be related.

When I hover over the down arrow in the top right of the screen on the PC, the cursor changes to a text insertion point "the I bar" rather than the pointing finger which usually indicates that something is clickable. Clicking has no effect.

When I hover over a vote icon, although a tooltip is displayed, the cursor does not change to indicate that the icon is clickable. Clicking has no effect.

I have also noticed some strange behaviour related to the links at the bottom of the page that allow users to swap between the mobile and full versions of the site. The cursor changes to a text insertion point when I hover over them. Also, clicking on this link in the meta.stackoverflow.com site has no effect other than to refresh the page.

Is anyone else able to reproduce this behaviour? Is there anything I can try to help isolate the problem?

Comment: How are you "hovering" over a link on a phone?  The lack of change when clicking "mobile" or "full site" sounds like a caching bug; are you seeing a cache breaker appended after refresh (something like `_=41245`)?  Note that we do not support using the mobile version of the site from desktop browsers, any bugs particular to them will be [meta-tag:status-declined].

Comment: My question was not clear (I have updated it now) but the experience that I described was when using the mobile version of the site on a PC.

Comment: Hmm. Can you actually reproduce this on the Windows Phone? Or is this something you're only seeing on the desktop browser now? As Kevin's comment indicates, the mobile theme is not designed to support desktop browsers.

Comment: @Cody Gray: I focused on the desktop browser because I thought it would be easier to reproduce there. The problem that I have within the Windows Phone browser is that the menu and vote icons don't have any effect. Note that I had been working with this browser without any problems up until about a week ago.

Comment: @Kevin Montrose: I just deleted the browsing history on my Windows Phone without any effect.

Comment: I seem to have the same problem on my iPhone. I think I am logged in, because the notification arrow changes when there is something new. It has been a while since I used the site there, maybe my login credentials semi-expired?

Comment: Thanks @Jan Fabry. I have rephrased the question to make it less Windows Phone specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be fixed with the next build.

Basically, a javascript error was introduced that only affected IE and prevented most (if not quite all) of the click handlers for mobile to not be registered on Windows Phone devices.

The lack of a cursor on hover will not be fixed, since it only manifests on desktop browsers.  It'd be a waste of bytes to fix it, essentially.

Comment: That is great news! Thanks for the feedback @Kevin Montrose. The hover cursor doesn't worry me at all - I just thought that it might be related to the other problems. Not to be a pain but can you say how frequently changes are published?

Comment: @Scott - at least once a day.